# NGrok and Laravel

Tags: laravel, ngrok

I want to deploy my local larvel website online with NGROK.
I'm using Laragon with Apache server, I use this command :

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite site.dev:80
```

It almost work, but the asset file (like CSS/Image) are still link to my local server (site.dev). And it's the same for my link, the laravel routing command :
`{{ route('ngo') }}` return site.dev/ngo instead of my online tunnel (http://number.ngrok.io/ngo)

I've try to :

Edit the http.conf (https://forum.laragon.org/topic/88/allow-outside-other-devices-phones-tablets-to-access-your-local-server-using-ngrok)

Change my Laravel App url in config/app.php

Change my url in .env file

Nothings work

Answer (score 28):

I ran into this problem myself just now, but also found a way to fix it:

Run the ngrok command without the `-host-header=rewrite` part, resulting in

`ngrok http site.dev:80`

After this, edit your http.conf file and add the ngrok domain as a server alias. For example:

`ServerAlias nd3428do.ngrok.io`

The problem is that Laravel's `route` helper uses the `HOST` header, which is rewritten to `site.dev`. Without the `-host-header` part, the header isn't rewritten and now it works.

Comment: This was really useful. Just an annotation: it should be ngrok http site.dev:80

Comment: Haha.. stupid fingers typing the wrong characters :) I've edited it! :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent ~8 hours today battling with Twilio, and your post here was the best hint I found for solving the problem.

Comment: Can anyone speak into how to ensure logging in also works? Mine is not working presumably due to mismatch of session cookie domain names. I wonder if this can be solved and added to the answer.

Comment: It helped me in my PayPal project. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Got an efficient solution just follow this tips from this repository.
https://github.com/jn-jairo/laravel-ngrok

Comment: If you could give a brief summary, that would be great just in case the link you posted may not remain available