# Laragon could not detect Ngrok tunnel link

Tags: ngrok, laragon

So I tried to use [Laragon's Quick Share](https://laragon.org/docs/quick-share.html).

I have already authenticated my `ngrok agent`. But Laragon seems to ignore it (and idk y), so I have to set that manually in my project .yml config file.

*myproject.yml*

```
web_addr: localhost:4041
authtoken: 1t3...
```

**The problem is that the forwarding URL leads me to *localhost/index.php* (Laragon's Getting Started page) and not to my project. Also Laragon's warning shows "Could not detect Ngrok tunnel link".**

**What am I missing here?**

`Laragon Full 5.0.0`
`Ngrok 2.3.40`

Comment: same problem with me. are you found any solution ?

Comment: @IshtiaqAhmed Hi, try doing this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490688/ngrok-and-laravel). Though modifying the vhost config and restarting the server every time you do a quick share can be quite annoying.

Comment: This seems to be related to having an IPv6 address. With an IPv6 address, the resulting Ngrok url is much longer. Laragon doesn't seem to like that.